# Checking python package age in CI

Tags: python, pip, continuous-integration

Is there a tool which does not only verify if you are on the lastest version of a python package, but also how old that "lastest" version actually is? The use case is simply abandonware packages which got replaced by forks (Example: flask-security being dead and replaced by flask-security-too ... which actually is relevant to application security).

All the tools I've found only verify that you use the latest package version, which is *not* what I'm looking for.

Ideally it should be able to easily fail a CI build if an issue is found (i.e. ability to define limits instead of just outputting text) as well as have an ignore-list.

Basically something where I'd have a call like `sometool requirements.txt -max-age=365 -max-revisions=10 -max-latest-age=730` and it highlights all packages that are either more than 10 revisions behind, where my revision is over a year behind latest, or where the latest is released over 2 years ago.

Comment: maybe having own pypi mirror repository, which check all the version and add condition from there, and use this mirror repo for the CI process

Comment: @sahasrara62 that sounds like a lot of pointless work for simply verifying a date ...

Comment: then I think, need to create a scrapper that tell the release history of a package from PyPI,(don't know if it exists or not )

Comment: @sahasrara62 first no you don't, pypi has an api. secondly projects like that already exist but none checks the actually relevant information here (when the last version of a package was released) or allow to fail CI based on criteria. That's the whole point of the question.